# SQL: Column invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Column 'DocumentMetadata.Custodian' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

```
SELECT Custodian Field
    ,FlagName
    ,count(1) Counts
FROM DocumentMetadata t
INNER JOIN documentreview.dbo.documentflags df ON t.documentid = df.documentid
INNER JOIN documentreview.dbo.flags f ON df.flagid = f.flagid
WHERE t.documentId IN (
        SELECT DocumentId
        FROM DocumentReview.dbo.DocumentsInSample
        WHERE SampleId = 10039
        )
    AND df.flagid = 10117

UNION

SELECT Custodian Field
    ,f2.FlagName
    ,count(1) Counts
FROM DocumentMetadata t2
INNER JOIN DocumentReview.dbo.DocumentVetting dv2 ON t2.documentid = dv2.documentid
INNER JOIN DocumentReview.dbo.FlagRelevancyMapping frm2 ON frm2.CategoryFolderId = dv2.CategoryId
INNER JOIN DocumentReview.dbo.Flags f2 ON f2.FlagId = frm2.FlagId
WHERE dv2.DocumentId IN (
        SELECT DocumentId
        FROM DocumentReview.dbo.DocumentsInSample
        WHERE SampleId = 10039
        )
    AND f2.FlagId IN (10117)
    AND f2.IsCategoryFlag = 1
    AND (
        frm2.Relevancy = dv2.Relevancy
        OR (
            frm2.Relevancy = 'MR'
            AND dv2.MaybeResolved = 1
            )
        OR (
            frm2.Relevancy = 'CCA'
            AND dv2.CrossCheckAgree = 1
            )
        OR (
            frm2.Relevancy = 'CCD'
            AND dv2.CrossCheckDisagree = 1
            )
        OR (
            frm2.Relevancy = 'VM'
            AND dv2.VettingMismatch = 1
            )
        OR (
            frm2.Relevancy = 'VMR'
            AND dv2.VettingMismatchResolved = 1
            )
        )
GROUP BY Custodian
    ,FlagName
ORDER BY Custodian
    ,FlagName
```

Comment: Maybe you should try printing the SQL script it generated and reviewing it yourself.  Stack Overflow isn't your personal debugger that you can submit code to and have it magically fixed.

Comment: I did, and I couldn't find anything wrong with it. hence, me being here asking this question. If you cannot help, please do not post a comment

Comment: You need to help us help you.  If you can't do that, please do not post a question.

Comment: There are quite a few things that would fail most code reviews in here. You are casting to varchar with specifying the size, this means it will use the default. Do you know that default? Are you 100% certain that MS will never change it? You are using ANSI-89 style joins all over the place. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins This is also open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ This things needs a complete overhaul/rewrite.

Comment: You say that you printed out the dynamic sql before executing it. That is where the problem is. Perhaps you could post the contents of that so that we can help you.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY Custodian, FlagName` before the `UNION`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis around the bottom query in the UNION.

Otherwise you are creating a derived table without an alias.

The reason for the error is because you don't close that parenthesis at all.

If "MR" is a value and not a column name, then you need to wrap it (and all others like it) in double single-quotes, like this:  `''MR''`

Comment: Another issue with his query is in the `OR` statements: `frm2.Relevancy = MR` - referencing a string value without quotes.

Comment: True, unless those are unambiguous column names...

Comment: So this entire query itself is written as a string which is why the value "MR" is not in quotes. I did not write this query. I am using it from a old ssrs project and adjusting a few things so I do not have to write one from scratch.